# model -> observer -> view -> controller -> model ->

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I'm reading on design patterns and while authors agree that observer pattern is cool, when it comes to design, everybody talks MVC.

I'm a bit confused, MVC diagram is not circular, isn't it natural for code flow to have closed topology ? Why nobody talking this pattern:

```
model -> observer -> view -> listener -> model -> ..
```

If view needs controller, then model needs observer, no ? With Object.observe() coming with next JavaScript version, **what is wrong with such a pattern** ?
[image: my pattern]

Comment: One small note - `Object.observe()` has been deprecated, `Proxy()` I believe is its replacement and is part of the ES2015 standard https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The View and and the Controller are both, also, observers.

The view /is/ an observer, of events on the model. The controller /is/ an observer of events in the view. The controller fires commands at the model, which results in it changing which propagates events which are observed by the view which changes its state appropriately.

The problem this is trying to solve is having a UI respond to changes in a model, and having the model respond to input from a user via a UI. There is no great reason to have a third component involved in this, other than the frailty of human vision -- it is far easier to envision a command and control system than an event driven system, though surprisingly the latter is often easier to implement.

One problem with your proposed design is separation of concerns. With MVC (when done properly, with messages/events) each component only knows about itself and its own concerns. With the model you're proposing the Observer component must know how to orchestrate the view, something which the view is better placed to do itself.

Of course, you're thinking that the controller orchestrates changes to the model, so why wouldn't we have an equivalent component on the far side of the relationship?

In fact, although we do typically implement something in the 'controller' space, it's often just 'infrastructure' to pass messages/events/commands from the view to the model, which responds accordingly -- that is, often the controller devolves into a simple router. The need for an orchestration component has been reduced in modern designs due to our better understanding of DDD and the aggregate-root pattern, and of course the possibilities of event-sourcing.

Finally, the pattern you're referring to was originally documented by the Gang of Four as existing in practice and relatively common. At the time there were no mobile or webapps, and one of the largest systems they considered was gimp. As our technologies have matured and our apps are delivered via multiple channels so have the patterns of development in this space. A few years back we were discussing MVC2, then we moved on to oddities like MVVC and MMVC. Now, with CQRS, event-sourcing, and DDD, we have started talking about MV as the orchestration approach has started showing its limitations and event driven systems come to the fore.

Comment: As far as I understand, view can not control the model, so the view should control the controller ?

Comment: In MVC the view cannot change the model directly, that's what the controller does. The controller responds to events in the view by orchestrating changes in the model.

Comment: Oh well, I have to read 'bout 'CQRS, event-sourcing, and DDD' then. I'll mark your answer in advance, hopefully answer is there.